# css and images not working wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created custom wordpress theme. Everything works fine in my local. But when I moved it to the server css and images are not showing up. However, when I checked the 'view source' they are loading.

[image: Screenshot web:]

[image: Screenshot view source:]

Its the same with admin (wp-admin), css is not working but I can see it in 'view source'

URL: http://advertisement.aszstaging.com

*Its kind of strange!! I checked with my friends, its working for 4 out of 6!! What might be the issue?! 
-Checked in Chrome and Firefox
-Refreshing many times*

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is working fine. Just `/wp-content/themes/advertise/css/animations.css` is not found. Please load it.

Comment: @Hassan, I am not using it, so I just removed that link. But still not working.

Comment: It's working here too. Just http://advertisement.aszstaging.com/wp-content/themes/advertise/js/css3-animate-it.js is not loading

Comment: it's working here too..just shift+refresh your browser.

Comment: @BlueRose I dont know man!! I checked with my friends system, its working for 2 out of 6!! What might be the issue?!

Comment: @ManindraSingh Its kind of strange!! :D Working for some, not working for others!! Please help me on this. Have been googling for about 1 hour. Not able to find any clue!!

Comment: @AasimHussainKhan: shift+refresh your page or try any other browser.

Comment: @ManindraSingh No Luck.

Comment: If it's not a cache issue on your side it could be a server problem (if it just happen on few page loads). I noticed important response time from server for some of you css / js files (up to 15 - 20 seconds).

Comment: Could you check in your browser console the status of the css file when it is broken? It is 200, 304... ?

Comment: @vard, its isnt breaking

Comment: @AasimHussainKhan Mmh so you solved your issue?

Comment: @vard No, I mean nothing is breaking in console. However its still not working.

Comment: @AasimHussainKhan All right, so what's the status code? 200?

Comment: Identified that the "AdBlock Plus" browser add-on started blocking Wordpress styles 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identified that the "AdBlock Plus" browser add-on is blocking Wordpress styles because the url had 'advertisement'. Now I changed the url and css is working.

Answer (score 0):

It is loading perfectly fine. May be there is some cache issue. Please refresh **Ctrl+F5**.

.[image: See the screenshot]

Comment: this should be a comment. not answer.

Comment: I needed to post image. so that @afelixj. can't post image in comment

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem and tried all solutions i could find.
and then i checked wordpress rource file location and for me it was

```
/wp-content/themes/MYFOLDER
```

so i tried to edit like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/MYFOLDER/style.css">
```

from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

and this worked

Answer (score -1):

Following steps are follow for check your stylesheet path.
- Open function.php in theme folder.

### - Find style sheet and check you css path.

Load our main stylesheet.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyfourteen-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/your_stylesheet.css');
                     OR
```

It is loading perfectly fine. May be there is some cache issue. Please refresh Ctrl+F5.

Comment: @Kanu I am adding the stylesheet in header.php


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />

Comment: who down voted me?? why?? i m asking him coz he just paste this code without any explanation.